# The resource FileWriter of a try-with-resources statement cannot be assigned

Tags: java

I need to split a FileWriter into multiple partitioned files using "try-with-resources" technique.
But when I use "try-with-resources", I can't recreate the FileWriter and BufferWriter in a different file.
I'm trying to solve some sonar issues and "try-with-resources" is a rule to follow.

Does anyone have an idea to solve it?

Thanks

....

```
try (InputStream fis=new FileInputStream(sArquivo);
BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis)); 
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(sNomeArquivoDestino);
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw)) {                
     String vLinha = "";
     while (br.ready())
     {
         vLinha = br.readLine();
         if(vLinha == null) { break; }                              
         bw.write(vLinha+System.lineSeparator());                 
         if (lLinhas % lLimiteLinhas == 0L && lLinhas > 0L)
         {                   
             bw.flush();
             bw.close();                     
             ++lPart;
             sNomeArquivoDestino = sPathDestino+"\\"+sFileName.replace(".TXT", "")+"-Part-"+ String.format("%05d" ,lPart)+".TXT";
             fw = new FileWriter(sNomeArquivoDestino);    // Compile error: The resource fw of a try-with-resources statement cannot be assigned         
             bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);    // Compile error: The resource bw of a try-with-resources statement cannot be assigned         
         }                                  
         ++lLinhas; 
     }             
 }
 catch (Exception ex)
 {           
     throw ex;
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the BufferedWriter is used to write several numbered partial files, one does not have an automatically closing file for a try-with-resources syntax.

Easiest is to have a `finally` block and do all oneself. Of course one could also introduce a second nested loop with try-with-resources for the output of a part.

First I would use Files, Path, and Paths for a shorter usage of otherwise nested file constructors. Also the text encoding of the computer is the default one. Better make it explicit. (Best would have been `StandardCharsets.UTF_8` for full Unicode power, when possible.)

Using `ready()` is wrong, as it is a test, whether a read will block (the current buffer is empty). Here the right thing to do is to request a read. Otherwise you might be so fast, still nothing is there, and though there is still something on disk, you stop reading.

One might use `sNomeArquivoDestino = String.format("...%s ...", ..., ...);` for a nicer style.

```
    Charset charset = Charset.defaultCharset();
    Path arguivo = Paths.get(sArguivo);
    BufferedWriter bw = null;
    try (BufferedReader br = Files.newBufferedReader(arguivo, charset)) {
        long lPart = 0;
        long lLinhas = 0L;
        for (;;) {
            String vLinha = br.readLine();
            if (vLinha == null) {
                break;
            }
            if (lLinhas % lLimiteLinhas == 0L) {
                if (bw != null) {
                    bw.close();
                    bw = null;
                }
                sNomeArquivoDestino = sPathDestino + "\\"
                    + sFileName.replace(".TXT", "") + "-Part-"
                    + String.format("%05d", lPart) + ".TXT";
                Path arquivoDestino = Paths.get(sNomeArquivoDestino);
                bw = Files.newBufferedWriter(arquivoDestino, charset);
                ++lPart;
            }
            bw.write(vLinha);
            bw.write(System.lineSeparator());
            ++lLinhas;
        }
    } finally {
        if (bw != null) {
            bw.close();
        }
    }
```

*By the way, Hungarian notation with prefixes like `s` and `l` are not common in java, in favor of more fluent names. (Compare old MS C++ with Linux C++.)*

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to change your logic to use try-with-resources *inside* try-with-resources. In pseudo code:

```
try (fis; br):
    for each partition in br:
        try (fw; bw):
            write partition to bw
```

Assuming that you should always write at least one partition, this could be done changed a bit:

```
try (fis; br):
    while (true):
        try (fw; bw):
            write partition
            - continue when the partition is full
            - break when no more data
```